# creating session in userlog in page asp.net website using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am trying to create session in my ASP.NET website to save current user, but the word `session` doesn't appear as a reserved word and I keep getting error messages!! Can anyone help?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
public partial  class login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public static string x;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from UserInformation where UserName =@username and Password=@password", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUserName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPWD.Text);
        //System.DateTime.Now
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("myprofile.aspx"); 
        }
        else
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script    language='javascript'>alert('خطأ في اسم المستخدم او كلمة المرور')</script>");
        }
    }
    protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused... where's the "session" now?

Comment: What error are you getting? A class that extends System.Web.UI.Page should have a Session object that you can manipulate.

Comment: Look into asp.net forms authentication

Comment: Session is an `Object` you can just create the Session for example `Session["username"] = txtUserName.Text;` also if you are only passing 2 fields to the Database why don't you change the Select * to Select the necessary field(s) that you need. `Please State where you are trying to create the Session` cant tell based on the code that you have provided..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Session is an inherited property of `login` so you can set session values like: `this.Session["key"] = value;`